# My code keeps running the even when it reach the else and return statement, I have a recursion in the if statement ? the answer is 589.45

Tags: python

```
def max_increase(seq):
    if len(seq) == 0 :
        return 0
    elif type(seq) != list:
        max_increase(list(seq))
    elif seq.index(max(seq)) < seq.index(min(seq)):    
        max_increase(seq[seq.index(min(seq)):])
    else: 
        return max(seq) - min(seq)
            
            
            
btc_data = [ 6729.44, 6690.88, 6526.36, 6359.98, 6475.89, 6258.74,
                 6485.10, 6396.64, 6579.00, 6313.51, 6270.20, 6195.01,
                 6253.67, 6313.90, 6233.10, 6139.99, 6546.45, 6282.50,
                 6718.22, 6941.20, 7030.01, 7017.61, 7414.08, 7533.92,
                 7603.99, 7725.43, 8170.01, 8216.74, 8235.70, 8188.00,
                 7939.00, 8174.06 ]
btc_data.reverse()


max_increase(tuple(btc_data))
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and ask an actual question instead of just posting code and treating the title itself as the place you (sort of) ask a question.

Comment: Do you now what 'title' means?

Comment: Presumably your recursive calls should be `return max_increase(...)`, not just `max_increase(...)`? Otherwise the inner calls are meaningless, their results are never conveyed to the outer call.

Comment: This does not keep running.

Comment: Not sure, but recursive calls that don't do something with the return value, iike `max_increase(list(seq))` are usually suspect. Also, floating point math can be tricky. There isn't really a 589.45 but there is a 589.450000000000045474735088646411895751953125.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

since you are using `recursion` you need to use `return` statment with the functional call and exit condition. In your code, you haven't used `return` with function call that is why it is keep running.

```
def max_increase(seq):
    if len(seq) == 0 :
        return 0
    elif type(seq) != list:
        return max_increase(list(seq))
    elif seq.index(max(seq)) < seq.index(min(seq)):    
        return max_increase(seq[seq.index(min(seq)):])
    else: 
        return max(seq) - min(seq)
            
            
            
btc_data = [ 6729.44, 6690.88, 6526.36, 6359.98, 6475.89, 6258.74,
                 6485.10, 6396.64, 6579.00, 6313.51, 6270.20, 6195.01,
                 6253.67, 6313.90, 6233.10, 6139.99, 6546.45, 6282.50,
                 6718.22, 6941.20, 7030.01, 7017.61, 7414.08, 7533.92,
                 7603.99, 7725.43, 8170.01, 8216.74, 8235.70, 8188.00,
                 7939.00, 8174.06 ]
btc_data.reverse()


print(max_increase(tuple(btc_data)))
```

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode have you read the OP question title ?